# Google indexed my sitemap successfully but showing 0 URLs discovered. How do I fix that?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, yoast

About two weeks ago, I submitted my sitemap in webmaster of my site https://example.com. It's successfully index, but there's not any single URL discovered. It shows 0 there now.  Three weeks have past, but nothing has changed. I indexed my each post manually.

Comment: Sitmaps don't really matter for SEO.   See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).   As long as your site is indexed, it doesn't really matter what Google is showing in search console for the sitemap.

Answer (score 1):

Google crawls pages on it's own schedule.  A new site probably has a lower priority than an already existing site with lots of existing traffic.  You might want to simply submit a few individual pages to Google Search Console via Inspect URL.

My experience is that it takes about 7-10 days from submitting them via GSC for them to affect the number of pages Google displays.

Even so, Google will still do what it wants to do, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Well **Sitemap** does help Google for crawling all of your site. However, this case will only worked while your site was `indexed`. Do you try to inspect your website by pasting it into **Google Search Console** under `inspect` there. You may check your website status.

For `inspect` information, try [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en).

If you site was not crawl yet, you may try to re index your page again in **Google Search Console**, well it takes time for Google to crawl a page.

Hope it helps!